# Prevent escape sequence interpretation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, string

I want to escape correctly a windows path that I get from cmd command.

for example when I tap **where node** in cmd, I will get a path like this :

```bash
C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Roaming\npm\ts-node
```

This is not a correct escaped string That I can pass between variable and it is not json validated.

I want to write a function that escape correctly this string.

```js
const input = "C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Roaming\npm\ts-node"
const output = "C:\\Users\\mypc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ts-node"
```

I tried spliting the string, and many tries, but did'nt works.

When I console log the input, It will console like this, converting **\n (in \node)** as linebreak and **\t in (\ts-node)** as tab.

```js
console.log(input)
/* 
C:UsersmypcAppDataRoaming
pm      s-node
*/
```

I find a pretty solution using String.raw like this :

```js
const solution_1 = String.raw`C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Roaming\npm\ts-node`
console.log(solution_1)
// C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Roaming\npm\ts-node
```

The problem is that I can't pass a variable to String raw

```js
const input = "C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Roaming\npm\ts-node"
const solution_2 = String.raw`${input}`
console.log(solution_2)
/* 
C:UsersmypcAppDataRoaming
pm      s-node
*/
```

I need a solution to pass a variable to String.raw or other technique to escape a string by a function.

Comment: If the string with those characters comes from somewhere outside your code, such as the command line or (in a browser) an `<input>` field, there is no need to escape the characters. Escaping is necessary when a string is "born" as a string constant inside JavaScript code. Some other environments (such as HTML) have their own syntactic rules and may require other kinds of escaping for string values created there.

Comment: Thank you @Pointy for your answer. I threat the case when the string is born inside a javacsript code. How I can espace the backslashes ?

Comment: @ayoubdev add another backslash when defining the variable or use a slash.  `const path = "C:/some/file"` will be handled like `const path = "C:\\some\\file"` when you are interacting with the file system.

Comment: @Christopher. yes, I know this. I want to build a function that do this without doing it manually.

Comment: You don't have to do that; Node does it for you.

Comment: There is no way to disable the requirement to escape special characters when defining strings inside the script like in your solution 2 or your first example. You **have to** escape the backslashes or use a slash if you write a path (or something similar) inside your script. -- [Specification - Literals - String Literals](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-literals-string-literals)

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing code and values. Code is what you write in your text editor. Obviously since source code in various programming languages have syntax and that syntax use the same characters that can appear in data there are some data that must be written differently in source code.

For example, if you want to write the data `"Hello'` in code you must either write:

```
let data1 = "\"Hello'"
```

or

```
let data2 = '"Hello\''
```

This is because the javascript language interprets the characters `"` and `'` as part of its syntax. But let's be **VERY CLEAR** about this. Both `data1` and `data2` contain exactly the same data. That is, they both contain:

```
"Hello'
```

They don't contain `\"Hello'` or `"Hello\'`. You must understand this completely in order to not confuse yourself. Source code is not the same as the value of the data. Source code is just a way we write the data so that our programming language understand it.

When you do:

```
const input = "C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Roaming\npm\ts-node"
```

The value of `input` is:

```
C:UsersmypcAppDataRoaming
pm    s-node
```

You need to write that data in a different way so that it will have the right value. You need to write:

```
const input = "C:\\Users\\mypc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ts-node"
```

The value of `input` is now:

```
C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Roaming\npm\ts-node
```

Let's remind ourselves again. This is the **VALUE** of the variable. The variable **DOES NOT** actually contain `C:\\Users\\mypc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ts-node`.

Now, here's another example. I'm creating a text file called "path.txt" and in it I write:

```
C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Roaming\npm\ts-node
```

Very carefully note what I'm writing in my text file. This is not a javascript source code. This is just data. I'm not writing `C:\\Users\\mypc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ts-node` because I'm not writing javascript here. I'm just writing data.

Now if I do this:

```
let data3 = fs.readFileSync('path.txt');
```

The value of data3 is:

```
C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Roaming\npm\ts-node
```

That's right. Javascript **DOES NOT** interpret the escape sequence **AT ALL**. Let me remind you again. Javascript does not interpret string escape sequence in data (eg, data you entered from the terminal or a file). It only does that in source code.

So. The answer to

> I want to escape correctly a windows path that I get from cmd command.

Is you need to do nothing at all. There is no escaping being done by javascript.

But note: command shells like cmd.com or PowerShell on Windows or bash, dash, tcsh, fish etc. on Linux and Mac OS also have their own syntax. So in order to write the command correctly so that your shell (eg. cmd.com) will pass the correct data to your node.js process you need to understand your shell's syntax.

I don't use Windows so I'm not sure what you need to write on cmd.com to get it right but on Linux/Mac OS, assuming I have this script:

```
// testing.js

let data = process.argv[2];
console.log(data);
```

I can execute the script like this:

```
node ./testing.js C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Roaming\npm\ts-node
```

This is because bash (the shell I'm using) does not escape the `\` character.